# Removing from a sublist, inserting into another one

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration

From a list like

```
test = {{1, 3}, {2,7, 8}, {5,6}};
```

I would like to randomly select `k` elements, lift them out of their current sublist and place them into a different random sublist and sort the sublist.

Desired output should look like:

```
 RandomSwap[test]
 {{1}, {2,7}, {3,5,6,8}};

 RandomSwap[test]
 {{1,7}, {2,6}, {3,5,8}};
```

I can get the indexes of the elements I need to swap by doing (if I'm looking for 2 elements in this tiny example)

```
 k =2
 ListIndexes = RandomSample[Range[Length[test]], k]
```

Then select a random number of entries in each sub list

```
 ElementsIndexes =  Flatten[RandomSample[#, 1] & /@ Range[Map[Length, child[[MutationIndexes]]]]]
```

But I don't know how to perform the swaps in an efficient/vectorized way.

Answer (score 2):

This selects positions from the indices of the ragged array, `Delete`s these positions, and then `Insert`s the deleted values into new randomly selected sublist (excluding the source sublist). The `Sort` can be included in the function if needed.

```
randomSwap[list_, k_] :=
 With[{pos = 
    RandomSample[Flatten@MapIndexed[#2 -> #1 &, list, {2}], k]},
  Fold[
   Insert[#1, Last@#2, First@#2] &,
   Delete[list, Keys@pos],
   MapAt[
     {RandomChoice[DeleteCases[First@#]@Range@Length@list], -1} &,
     {All, 1}]@pos
   ]
  ]
```

With `test` as in OP for 5 examples

```
SeedRandom[321]
Sort /@ randomSwap[test, #] & /@ Range@5 // Column
```

> ```
> {{1,3,7},{2,8},{5,6}}
> {{1,3},{7},{2,5,6,8}}
> {{1,2},{3,6,7,8},{5}}
> {{1,7},{},{2,3,5,6,8}}
> {{1,5},{6,8},{2,3,7}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
RandomSwap[list_, k_] := Module[{range, pos, move},
     range = Range[Length[list]];
       pos = Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, {range, Length /@ list}];
      move = RandomSample[PadRight[RandomInteger[{1, Length[list] - 1}, k], Length[pos]]];
       pos = Mod[pos + move, Length[list], 1];
  TakeList[(Join @@ list)[[Ordering[Transpose[{pos, Join @@ list}]]]],
           Lookup[Counts[pos], range, {}]]]

RandomSwap[test, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 8}, {6}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = {{1, 3}, {2,7,8}, {5,6}};

len = Length@Flatten@test;
nlists = Length@test;

Table[
  TakeList[RandomSample[Flatten@test, len]
    , RotateLeft[
     RandomChoice[IntegerPartitions[len, {nlists}]]
     , RandomInteger[{1, nlists}]]
    ] // Map[Sort]
  , 10] // Grid
```

[image]

Thus all numbers are included once and the number of lists in the input are retained.